# Connect orbeon 3.8 to external exist database v. 1.4.1

Tags: orbeon, xforms, exist-db

I am trying to connect Orbeon Forms to external exist database. So I added parameter

```
<property as="xs:anyURI"
          name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.exist.uri"
          value="http://orbeon:secret@localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>
```

to **properties-local.xml** as written here http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/exist-configuration#TOC-Configuring-Form-Runner but that doesn't work, orbeon still trying to connect to embeded exist DB, and says that DB is already locked by some another DB instance (it's external exist instance). I was trying to change web.xml to turn off all embeded exist servlets, but still no result.

What am I doing wrong?

May be there another configurations need to be changed?

Thanks, for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies.

The problem was that I configured the same directory storage for the external exist, as for the embeded one. So when orbeon was starting the embeded DB had no opportunity to connect to already occupied files.

So after I reconfigured **exist-conf.xml** in orbeon/WEB-INF, orbeon managed to start and connect to external DB.

Answer (score 1):

With 3.8, Orbeon Forms was using eXist to store some internal XForms state (in addition to being the default Form Runner persistence). This use of eXist has since been removed in 3.9 and newer. This probably explains why Orbeon Forms stills tries to connect to your local eXist database.

With 3.8, the following properties configure access to eXist for XForms state handling:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.username"              value="guest"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.password"              value="guest"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.uri"                   value="xmldb:exist:///"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.collection"            value="/db/orbeon/xforms/cache/"/
```

By updating those, you should be able to point to your external eXist and completely remove the use of the internal eXist.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the problem was that I defined for new exist database storage the same directory as for the old embeded one. So since I reconfigured embeded exist, orbeon started, and began to connect to external db.